# gnosis safe: encoding simulated transactions

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, gnosis-chain

I am trying to batch multiple actions inside of a metadata transaction like so:

```js
const transactions: MetaTransactionData[] = [{
    to: MODULEPROXYFACTORY,
    data: factoryInit,
    value: "0",
    operation: 1
  }, {
    to: PROXY,
    data: enableModuleData, // Cannot exist yet because the contract is not deployed
    value: "0",
    operation: 1
}]
```

I want to first deploy and then enable that same module (which doesn't exist before the transaction is executed). This should be possible by simulating the transactions and then encoding the necessary data.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take:

1. The `setup` method allows you to make an optional delegate call which could be a call to a library that enables modules:

```
   /// @dev Setup function sets initial storage of contract.
   /// @param _owners List of Safe owners.
   /// @param _threshold Number of required confirmations for a Safe transaction.
   /// @param to Contract address for optional delegate call.
   /// @param data Data payload for optional delegate call.
   /// @param fallbackHandler Handler for fallback calls to this contract
   /// @param paymentToken Token that should be used for the payment (0 is ETH)
   /// @param payment Value that should be paid
   /// @param paymentReceiver Address that should receive the payment (or 0 if tx.origin)
   function setup(
       address[] calldata _owners,
       uint256 _threshold,
       address to,
       bytes calldata data,
       address fallbackHandler,
       address paymentToken,
       uint256 payment,
       address payable paymentReceiver
   ) external {}
```

See `to` and `data` params. An example of the library:
https://github.com/rmeissner/relay-contracts/blob/main/contracts/EnableModulesLib.sol

2. The address can be pre-calculated. Please, see the documentation for calculating address for `CREATE` and `CREATE2` opcodes here:
   https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/deploying-with-create2#create